# Realm & React Native - Best practice to implement auto-updates?

Tags: react-native, realm

What are the best practices/patterns make realm a reactive datasource in a react native app? Especially for [presentational and container components pattern](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.drlaug899)?

Here is an example which I'd like to make reactive: [Realm with React Native](https://gist.github.com/Thorbenandresen/fc4bb5fb0ef6554d3ce5)

The [docs on auto-updates/change-events](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#change-events) are a bit thin and the [official example](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#examples) does not make use of this feature (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make your example reactive by subscribing to events and updating the ui when you receive a change event. Right now events are only sent when write transactions are committed, but finer grained change events will be added in the future. For now you could add the following constructor to update the ui on changes:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.realm = new Realm({schema:[dogSchema]})
  this.realm.addListener('change', () => {
    this.forceUpdate()
  });
}
```

You need to hold onto a Realm instance to keep the notifications alive, and you can use this Realm instance throughout the rest of the component.

Instead of calling `forceUpdate`, you could instead set the component's state or props within the event listener to trigger the refresh, like so:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.realm = new Realm({schema:[dogSchema]})

  this.state = {...}; // Initial state of component.

  this.realm.addListener('change', () => {
    this.setState({...}); // Update state instead of using this.forceUpdate()
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ari, how could I set the props into the event listener?. Replace `this.forceUpdate()` with `super(props)`?

Comment: For your example you would probably want to call `setState` instead. Rather than calculating `dogProp` in `render` you would instead put it in `state` which would automatically trigger a re-render. Something like `this.setState({dogProp: this.realm.objects('Dog').length})`. You would also want to implement `getInitialState`.

Comment: thanks again @Ari. Any way to do that without introducing local component state? (I am using Redux)

Comment: If you are using redux I would recommend just using Realm as a persistence layer and writing to Realm whenever you write to your redux store, using redux to trigger your ui to render when necessary. In the future we hope to have better integration. More info the the subject here: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/141

Comment: Isn't it better to add the listener in the componentWillMount() ? That way you can remove the listener in componentWillUnmount()

Comment: this solution sometimes causes "Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component"

Answer (score 9):

I think @Ari gave me a good answer for `redux` folks *as i was also struggling*. I'm not sure if it's immutable enough but it **works!**

I'm simpliy dispatching `getVehicles` action inside `addListener` and it just works!

**Below** is UI component whose constructor function makes the magic!

```js
//- importing my realm schema
import realm from '../../db/models';
//- Importing my action
import { getVehicles } from './../../actions/vehicle';


@connect((store) => {
    return {
        vehicle: store.vehicle.vehicles
    }
})
export default class Devices extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        realm.addListener('change', () => {
            props.dispatch(getVehicles());
        });

    }
}
```

**Below** is db/models file used up there in the constructor.

```js
import Realm from 'realm';

class VehicleSchema {};

VehicleSchema = {
    name: 'vehicleInfo',
    properties: {
        vehicleName: 'string',
        vehicleNumber: 'string',
        vehiclePassword: 'string',
        vehiclePasswordTrigger: 'bool',
        vehicleType: 'string',
        vehiclePicture: { type: 'data', optional: true }
    }
};

export default new Realm({schema: [VehicleSchema]});
```

**Below** is the actions/vehicle file, which gets dispatched in the constructor above.

```js
import { queryVehicle } from './../db/queryVehicle';

export function getVehicles() {

    const vehicles = queryVehicle();

    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({type: "GOT_VEHICLES", payload: vehicles});
    }
}
```

**Below** is my queryVehicle function that does the querying called in action file above.

```js
import vehicleModel from './models';

const queryVehicle = (queryInfo="vehicleInfo", filter='') => {

    const objects = vehicleModel.objects(queryInfo);

    if(filter.length === 0) return objects;

    let results = objects.filtered(filter);
    return results;


};

export { queryVehicle };
```

**disclaimer** I don't know if this code looks immutable enough, or following good redux practice cause i'm just starting out with redux so give me some comments advising if i'm doing something wrong.

I'll also guess `reducer` implementation wouldn't matter much in this here.

Answer (score 1):

Recently ran into an issue with Realm ListView auto-updating. When the ListView rows have varied heights, you can get overlaps on rows in the UI. The below was the only way I could get the ListView to re-render without causing UI overlaps. It seems a bit "dirty" to me, so if there is a better way, I welcome the input. But this is working perfectly so far; incase anyone else runs into this issue.

Basically it just wipes the dataSource, then inserts it again using the setState callback when there are `insertions` or `deletions`, but `modifications` simply roll through and auto-update.

```
let feed = this.props.store.feed;

feed.addListener((name, changes) => {
   if (changes.insertions.length || changes.deletions.length) {
       this.setState({dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows([])},
           () => this.setState({dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(feed)})
       );
   } else {
        this.setState({dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(feed)});
   }
});
```