# Fastest way to copy all realm data into JS object?

Tags: react-native, realm

I'd like to populate my redux store with my model state stored in Realm on app start. (As suggested here [Realm & React Native - Best practice to implement auto-updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902361/realm-react-native-best-practice-to-implement-auto-updates#comment59551838_35923260))

What is the fastest way to do so? Currently I am using `reduce` to create my JS object. Takes around 2 seconds in production for 2400 items. Is there a faster way?

```
const getRealmData = () => {

    let items = db.objects('Item')
    let allItems = items.reduce((r,v) => {
        r[v.item_id]= {
            article: v.article,
            excerpt: v.excerpt,
            given_title:v.given_title,[...]
        }
        return r
    }, {})

   return Immutable.fromJS(allItems)
}
```

Comment: We don't have any sort of batch read, so this is probably the fastest. 2 seconds sounds like a lot though. Do you have a very large number of properties on your class?

Answer (score 0):

Would you try like below ?

```
var plainResults = Array.prototype.map.call(items, (item) => {
  var object = {};
  for (var property of ItemSchema.properties) {
    object[name] = item[name];
  }
  return object;
});
```

Comment: I get the error: `Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined`. This is how the item inside the map.call  looks like: `Item {Symbol(): 9577, Symbol(): 9580, Symbol(): "object"}`. Btw. is there a difference between `Array.prototype.map.call(items` and `items.map(` ?