# Does Realm have a function like onAuthStateChanged of firebase for listening user auth state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm

I use the function `onAuthStateChanged` of firebase in react-native for control my current screen of routes by supervising user login status.

Now I made a app using realm from firebase, but I can't find any similar function, I just find some function like `Realm.Sync.User.login` `Realm.Sync.User.register`. Is there any solution or alternative for supervising user login status to control screen flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to Realm changes in your schema. It's really simple as realmCollection.addListener('change', ...). Check the Realm doc [here](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/).

You can even check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902361/realm-react-native-best-practice-to-implement-auto-updates) to see a practical example.